# Exporting Mathematica data and using it in excel

Tags: export, excel

1. I run this code:

   ```
    Test = {{{0.1`, 296.11467576123215`, 47.61904761904762`, 0}}, {{4.1`, 
        3227.227226761216`, 47.61904761904762`, 0}}, {{8.1`, 
        5263.260228203083`, 47.61904761904762`, 0}}}
    Export["OP.csv", Test]
   ```
2. I open this file with Excel
3. I remove all the braces
4. I use "Text to Columns"
5. An then I cannot do anything with the data in excel. If I multiply it with 2 I get an "value error"

I watched several Tutorials on Mathematican and Excel and it seems to me there should be no problem...

What can I do differently?

Comment: Maybe try `Export["OP.xls", Test,"XLS"]` or `Export["OP.xlsx", Test,"XLSX"]` ?

Comment: I have tried `Export["OP.xls", Test,"XLS"]` : it works. For example one can make the total of the first line in Excel.

Comment: Thx a lot. That solved it, together with another input structure in mathematica

Comment: Your table is 3 dimensionnal, so as a sheet is only 2D, the third dimension is interpeted as sheet change.